# component are displayed before loading data angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am currently developing an app with Angular 4. I am loading data from the webservice with http.get. It is displayed in a ng2-select, but unfortunately I always get the local variable empty and the UI is displayed  before the data is loaded.
Is there a way to load data then display the UI in Angular?
By the way, I have subscribed to the observable in the ngOnInit method and in the constructor, and in both cases the UI is first displayed then the data is loaded(I 
 got it in the console) and in this case the local variable is be empty.

this is the service method

```
getLanguagesList2():Observable<any>{
    this.languages=new Array<IOption>();
    return this.http.get('pmnweb3/mvc/metadata/languages')
    .map(res => res.json().items);
  }
```

this is component 's code
    languages:Array ;

```
public loading = true;
constructor(  private createUserService:CreateUserService,private languageService:LanguagesService) {
 this.languages=new Array<IOption> ();
  this.loading = true;
  this.languageService.getLanguagesList2().subscribe(data=>{

      data.forEach(element => {
        this.languages.push ({label:  element.languageName , value:  element.languageCode});
        console.log("label  "+  element.languageName+"  value  "+   element.languageCode);

      });

      this.loading = false;
  });
  console.log("my lang"+this.test); 


}
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Your webservice call is asynchronous. You will either need to implement it with a promise or observe and wait until the array with the select items is not empty.

Comment: the problem is how can i make it synchronous

Comment: u can check my code now

Comment: why not just tell the page to display only if it has data? thats the easiest way

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: in your html, add `*ngIf="languages.length > 0"` to one of your divs or something, im not sure on your html so i cant say for certain

Comment: already done thank you

Comment: in which case, if its put on the correct tag, the page wont load until it has data

Comment: I'll mark this as a duplicate, please ping me if you feel that it's not a duplicate. mast3rd3mon should be on the right track here :)